# Erro CORB/CORS ao requisitar api do google

Tags: node.js, ionic, angular

Tenho um projeto ionic-angular com servidor desenvolvido em nodejs. Estou tentando fazer uma autenticação de usuário enviando uma request para a api do google através do framework *Passport* utilizando a *Google-Strategy*.

Ao fazer a requisição, o seguinte erro acontece:

```
"Failed to load https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fuser%2Fgoogle%2Fredirect&scope=profile&client_id=976813214537-0a1kl69viqpgg5ibtcgt743secpsmrld.apps.googleusercontent.com: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405"
```

No meu servidor, já estou concedendo permissão à todas as origens de requisição. Por isso, não consigo entender por que estou tendo este problema.

O problema parece acontecer por eu estar utilizando o browser para testar a aplicação através do comando `ionic serve`. Até já adicionei uma extensão ao chrome que concede permissão às origens, porém não resolveu meu problema.

Answer (score 1):

Isso acontece porque antes da reuisição que você faz, é feita uma requisição "preflight" do tipo OPTIONS.

Esse problema pode ser corrigido nas configurações de CORS no servidor, mas quando você não tem acesso ao servidor, você pode usar um proxy.
Encontrei duas soluções que funcionaram:

1 - Usar o plugin [HTTP](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/)

Instale o plugin:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-advanced-http
npm install --save @ionic-native/http
```

Inclua no app.module.ts:

```
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http';
...
providers: [
    ...
    HTTP
  ]
```

Na sua página.ts:

```
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http';

const endereco: string = 'https://...'; //seu endereço

Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
    private http: HTTP) {
    })

  }

  requisicao(){
    this.http.get(endereco, {}, {})
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });    
  }

}
```

2 - Usar um proxy

Adicione um proxy antes do endereço que está tentando acessar.
Vi essa resposta em: [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource—when trying to get data from a REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe).
Exemplo usando o HttpClient:

Inclua no app.module.ts:

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
...
imports: [
    ...
    HttpClientModule
  ]
```

Na sua página.ts:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

const endereco: string = 'https://...'; //seu endereço

const proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";

Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
    private http: HttpClient) {
    })

  }

  requisicao(){
    this._http.get(proxyurl + endereco)
      .subscribe(
        (data) => {
          console.log(data);
        },
        (err) => {
          console.log(err);
        }
      );    
  }

}
```

Comment: Na minha requisição, o ionic chama um "router" que está codificada no meu servidor nodejs e o servidor faz a requisição para a api do google. Em ambas as soluções que você me passou, a requisição é feita diretamente do ionic para a api do google, sem chamar o servidor beck-end. A resposta que você me passou faz todo o sentido, porém, como eu faço este procedimento para que a requisição seja feita pelo servidor? Pois lá está a Google-Strategy configurada para fazer a autenticação. Ficaria assim: Ionic -> servidor nodejs -> Api Google.

Comment: Você consegue incluir o proxy no seu servidor? Assim, o endereço de envio da requisição seria proxy + endereço do Google-Strategy.

Comment: Nunca fiz isto, mas posso pesquisar a respeito. Muito obrigado