# Ajuda com autenticacao API REST IONIC 3

Tags: javascript, ionic, ionic3

Eu sou novo no desenvolvimento com ionic, e preciso fazer o login em uma API, onde eu preciso passar o cabeçalho de login e senha no formato base64, e também preciso enviar os dados do dispositivo pelo body...
ja tentei de tudo pelo google e nao consegui resolver...
Alguém pode me ajudar, por favor?

```js
private dispositivo = {
    "device_id" : "cleiton_device",
    "device_os_version" : "5.0",
    "device_model" : "ASUS_T00J",
    "device_name" : "ZENFONE",
    "device_manufacturer" : "ASUS INC",
    "device_api_version" : "19",
    "device_width": "800",
    "device_height": "600",
    "push_key":"token_retornado_pelo_firebase_tanto_no_android_quanto_ios"
  };
  webReturn: any;
  constructor(
    public http: Http
  ) {
    
  }

  
  efetuarLogin(matricula:string, senha:string) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let headersObj  = new Headers();
        headersObj.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(matricula + ":" + senha));
        headersObj.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , '*');
        headersObj.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT');
        headersObj.append('Accept','application/json');
        headersObj.append('content-type','application/json');
        
        console.log(headersObj);
        console.log(this.dispositivo);

        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers:headersObj});

        this.http.post(this.URL_API + 'login/loginapp', options)
          .subscribe(res => {
            this.webReturn = res;
            console.log('console do res' + this.webReturn);
          }, (err) => {
            reject(err);
            console.log('console do erro' + err);
          });
    });
  }
```

erro 1 :
OPTIONS API_KEY 405 (Method Not Allowed)

erro 2:
Failed to load API_KEY  Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405.

Comment: Inicialmente pensemos da seguinte forma: API_KEY 405 - Method not allowed, esse erro, ao que tudo indica, ocorre por que sua API não aceita requisições post nesta URL.
Quanto ao envio dos dados no corpo da requisição, faça: 
`this.http.post(this.URL_API + 'login/loginapp', { matricula: matricula , senha: senha }, options)`
Pois o segundo objeto do HTTP do angular/ionic é o body.

Comment: Talvez seja o mesmo problema que o da pergunta: [Erro CORB/CORS ao requisitar api do google](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/318890/erro-corb-cors-ao-requisitar-api-do-google#319262)